# Vertically align the top of a box to the top of the tallest box of a line

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes

This is a follow-up question on this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123392/add-a-marker-to-the-left-of-the-text).

I want to mark a line by putting a star to the left of it.  If the line contains a box that is tall, the marker should be aligned with the top of this box, not the bottom.  How to align something to the top of the tallest box of a line?

MWE (edited):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\marker{%
\strut\vadjust{\vbox to 0pt{
\kern-\dp\strutbox\smash{\llap{$\star$}}\vss}}%
\ignorespaces}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 1pt minus 3pt}

\begin{document}
Some text \marker\rule{1cm}{5em} some more text, all \newline in the same paragraph.  A paragraph, where\newline \rule{1cm}{2em} \marker some lines are marked with a star\newline that should be aligned with the tallest box of the line.
\end{document}
```

Compile this to see the problem: the stars should be aligned with the top of the black rectangles.

Edit: I changed the MWE to describe the problem in a more accurate way.  A `\par` break and skipping back up to the old line does, unfortunately, not solve the problem.

Comment: Will the tall box always be the first or only thing on the line, or could there be text prior to/following the tall box?

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, if there is a tall box in the line, it will _most often_ be right behind the star.  Ideally, I would like the solution to work whereever the tall box is on the line.  But a solution that handles the case of a box right behind the star would help a lot at the moment!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% ingen indentering av nya exempel

\makebox(0,0)[tr]{$\star$}\par
\nointerlineskip
\rule{1cm}{5em}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for not removing the charmingly cryptic `ingen indentering av nya exempel` comment from the code :-)

Comment: It looks promising, but I also have `\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 1pt minus 3pt}` in the code, so `\nointerlineskip` does not work.  Sorry, missed to erase the comment!

Comment: @MunHo change `\par` to `\par\nobreak\vskip-\parskip`

Comment: It certainly works in the MWE, but in my document I get a `Dimension too large` error every new page when I add `\nobreak\vskip-\parskip` (and, contrary to the MWE, a vertical space is inserted between the star and the ensuing text).  Without posting the whole of my code, I don't know how to exemplify this problem.  Is there any other way to raise the star to the top of the tallest box of the line, without a issuing a new paragraph?  Very grateful for your help, indeed!

Comment: I realised that a par break is not possible in my setting, see edited question.  Is it not possible to access the height of the tallest box of the present line somehow?